# how start up other apps and help to fill the data on android

Tags: android

I want to develop an app that help users to start up other apps which needs username and password,so I must start up other apps and help to fill the username and password into the login userface of the apps,
   for example,I want to start up an app that helps user to login the facebook and fill the username and password in the login userface of the facebook app in my app,now I only konw the name of the facebookapp,
   1.how to start up it in my app?(I don't know the package name of the app started up)
   2.when I have started the app,how to automatically fill the username and password?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't.

AFAIK, for example with HTC's "Sense", Facebook credentials are stored as a sync account in the accounts api.

Since I think it is not encouraged to override common Android use cases, you will have to find out which Accounts they are storing.

For this, try to find out how [android.accounts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/package-summary.html) is working. The SampleSyncAdapter deluivered with the SDK dev sample applications also is a good place to start.